# Troubles with importing numpy in Termux

Tags: python, numpy, termux

I'm currently using Termux 0.118.0, with Python 3.10.6 and numpy 1.23.2. When I try to import numpy, the following error happens

```
python
```

Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  3 2022, 23:02:14) [Clang 12.0.9 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d7 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
^[[A>>>

> > > import numpy as np
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 23, in 
> > > from . import multiarray
> > > File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in 
> > > from . import overrides
> > > File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in 
> > > from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
> > > ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libgfortran.so.5" not found: needed by /usr/lib/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.3.7.so in namespace (default)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 140, in 
from . import core
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 49, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

```
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
```

Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python"
- The NumPy version is: "1.23.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen failed: library "libgfortran.so.5" not found: needed by /usr/lib/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.3.7.so in namespace (default)

I'm not really sure what's wrong since it appears that I do have libgfortran.so.5
(apologies for the format of this question, I'm new to stack overflow and to programming in general)

```
apt-get install libgfortran5
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libgfortran5 is already the newest version (8.3.0-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Solved. Apparently I was using a faulty repo.